# How to clone git in Ruby with URL

Tags: ruby, git, git-clone

Is there a way to clone a git repository from a URL in Ruby? I have been looking and cannot seem to find an answer.  Anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`git`](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) gem:

```
require 'git'
Git.clone('git://repo.or.cz/rubygit.git', 'clone.git')
```

Comment: I don't have the repo URIs.  It won't let me use the URL.

Comment: @Busch, what does that mean? How can you expect to clone a repository without having its clone URL?

Comment: @Busch - at the end of the day the `git` gem simply wraps system calls - if it works with `git clone ...` it should work here. What error do you get?

Comment: I messed up.  You were right.  Apologies, @UriAgassi

Comment: How can you pass an https rather than an ssh. ssh is working but not https.