# Github-Linguist, Ruby version run over multiple repositories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, rubygems, github-linguist

I am trying to run the github linguist ruby verision, It runs on my computer, I am using visual studio. If i run the github-linguist it does give me the stats of percentage and type of language my repository have that is on local system.  ( using terminal commands )

[OutPut running Linguist using terminal visual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqft8.png)

Goal: To write a scripts in ruby that takes provided repository and provide me with the stats (similar to above screenshot) as described by github-linguist functionality.

Based on some research so far, all i have is following code.

```
require 'rugged'
require 'linguist'
target=""
repo = Rugged::Repository.new('https://github.com/NameOfRepo')
project=Linguist::Repository.new(repo,repo.head.target)
project.language
project.languages
```

But having error, and I need a guidance related to the error and a better way to reach my goal.
Error: [Error from script, Visual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaSDy.png)
I am new to ruby and I would like for some help ?

***I am aware of how to change my path to local clone repository path in above code. I am looking for help with writing scripts that traverse through online github repository and provide me the stats.***

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path to a directory to `Rugged::Repository.new()`, not a URL:

```
repo = Rugged::Repository.new('/home/ShaishavMaisuria/NameOfRepo')
```

FYI, the source code for the `github-linguist` executable is at [https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/bin/github-linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/e2f638d17598e84f6f91c2d03c2f3e27f22a2163/bin/github-linguist).

Comment: Yes I am aware about how to write the code for local clone repository. Based on my goal metioned. i want to traverse throughly my git repositories online. so I looking for help in regards of writing scripts that can traverse through online repositories and help me get languages. the source code, is helpfull but i am confused how to pursue my stated goal. would love to get some help.

Comment: Are you saying you're question is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516394/how-to-clone-git-in-ruby-with-url?

Comment: Not actually, cloning of github repository to local system takes a lot of memory resources and does tolls on time  if there are many github repository to traverse through. I am looking for something that allows to pursue my goal without cloning the project on local system rather the scripts travserses the repository online.

Comment: I see. Then maybe you could query the GitHub API to retrieve statistics computed by Linguist for existing projects?

Comment: would be possible to query for user based accounts and check the stats using the above code. how can i do it in ruby though. I would request you to please guide